# Arduino LED does not turn ON/Off using Python 3.7

Tags: arduino, python-3.7

Using Python 3.7 (64-bit) and Windows 10,  I could not get to turn on/off the LED of an arduino uno board.  When I run the code, only the Rx indicator lights and blinks the number of times indicated in the loop statement.

```
from pyfirmata import Arduino, util
import time

board = Arduino("COM3")
for x in range(10):
    board.digital[13].write(1)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    board.digital[13].write(0)
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: which Firmata firmware did you upload to your Arduino?

Comment: Hi Piglet, thank you for your reply.  I missed the part of uploading the Firmata firmware to my arduino.

Comment: the Rx led flashes because the Arduino receives data from your PC. but without the Firmata firmware on the Arduino it doesn't process any commands.

Comment: I consider this question "solved". Correct?

Comment: Yes-solved. Arduino is now working.